# Calling Remote Action Method only When User completes entering Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have been working on MVC4 Application where i am using Remote Data-Annotation to check whether UserName is already present in DB or not. But my problem is as soon as i enter first character in TextBox, it calls JSON method and for each character insert it is going to call JSON method but what i'm looking is, it should execute JSON only when User Completes Entering UserName into TextBox.

Here is my class where i have created object with Remote DataAnnotation

```
public class Student
{
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
        [StringLength(100)] //If i give minLength here as 3 then after entering 3 characters it is going to call JSON Method which i don't want so i removed minLength Attribute
        [Remote("IsAvailable", "Home", ErrorMessage = "{0} already in use!")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my JSON Method in my Home Controller where i am checking Username

```
public JsonResult IsAvailable(string UserName)
{
        bool blnResult = false;
        if (UserName != null)
        {
            blnResult = !objDBContext.Student.Any(X => X.UserName == UserName);
        }
        return Json(blnResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My View is simple for entering Username

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "*")
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Advance thanks to everyone for there valuable feedback!!

Comment: Please show the view and the JS associated

Comment: View is simple bro nothing much in that. I'm going to post above and i did not write any dedicated JS for Remote Validation.

Comment: You could use `$('#UserName').keyup(function() { return false } );` But note that what you claiming is not the default behavior. It will only validate on keyup if (1) you make a change and tab out (at which point validation is triggered (`onblur`) and (2) your then tab back in and start making changes.

Comment: There is no other way to call Remote validation after completion of input from User, instead of writting a Keyup function to avoid call everytime??

Comment: @Aslam.. Instead of an Edit, valuable suggestion is most welcome

Comment: You can also set the validator defaults - `validator.settings.onkeyup = false;` but that will do it for all elements

Comment: Ok then i will write a Jquery to return false until Blur occurs